# Why can't I read apostrophes using ifstream without it crashing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I'm using this code:

```
std::string word;
std::ifstream f((file_name + ".txt").c_str());
while (f >> word) {
    good_input = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        if (ispunct(word.at(i))) {
            word.erase(i--, 1);
        }
        else if (isupper(word.at(i))){
            word.at(i) = tolower(word.at(i));
        }
    }
```

Every time I read the word "doesn't" from a text file, I get this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Program: *directory*\SortingWords(Length).exe
>   File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\convert\istype.cpp
>   Line: 36
>   Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255
>   For more information please visit... [etc.]

When I click "abort", my program exits with code 3. Don't know if that's helpful?

It looks like it's got something to do with the apostrophe maybe? This code works find for all other words in my document up until this one. And works great with documents that don't include apostrophes, yet they include plenty of other punctuation...

I tried changing the encoding of the text file (simply made with notepad), but that didn't help. Generally found lots of complaints about apostrophes but no working answers. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: My guess is that's it's a smart quote, but I have no way of telling.

Comment: What if you take look at the file in a hex-editor, do the apostrophe take only a single byte? Is it the encoded value you would expect it to be? And if you catch the crash in a debugger, is it really where you expect it to be (i.e. in the piece of code you show us)? What are the values of the involved variables? Are they what you would expect?

Comment: I tried simply re-writing my file word by word rather than copying and pasting from the original source (as I had done before). A pain, but it has done the trick and is working for all sorts of punctuation and weird cases now. Sorry to have wasted your time(s)! Looks like a problem with the characters used. Otherwise, just to satisfy any curiosity, yes the errors were occurring exactly here (found using breakpoints) and the variables all looked absolutely fine!

Comment: You shouldn't need to use your own breakpoints to find the crash location by the way. VS should break automatically while debugging when an assertion is triggered, letting you go to the stack frame you care about to see exactly which call caused it and what the state of the program was.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation for `ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/ispunct) says:

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as
>   `unsigned char` and is not equal to `EOF`.

Visual C++ is nice enough to add an almost explicit message for this error if you link to the debug runtime (this is often the case with undefined behaviour - with the release runtime, it just crashes or behaves strangely; with the debug runtime, you get an error dialog box).

In theory, this means that in the character set used by your environment, `'` is not representable as an `unsigned char`, i.e. its character code is too big or too low.

In practice, this seems very unlikely and perhaps even impossible on Windows. It is much more likely that your file doesn't really contain an apostrophe but a character that merely *looks* like one, e.g. an accent: `´`

Here's how you can reproduce the problem in a simple manner:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    ispunct('\'');
    ispunct('´'); // undefined behaviour (crash or error message with Visual C++)
}
```

`isupper` has the same problem.

You can use those functions safely with `static_cast`, e.g.:

```
if (ispunct(static_cast<unsigned char>(word.at(i))))
```

Of course, now `ispunct` will return zero for the character. If you really need to cover `´`, you have to do so explicitly, for example with a helper function like this:

```
bool extended_ispunct(int c)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned char>(c) || c == '´';
}
```

Comment: By the way, `cout << ((char)'´' == '´')` prints 0 on [this online MSVC compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).

Comment: @chris: Add `/W4`. It will tell you why: `warning C4310: cast truncates constant value`. In fact, `´` is 498440 on my machine.

Comment: @chris: True, that's a bug in my function! :) Thanks for spotting it, let me fix it...